# Как хранить список населенных пунктов (3 млн. записей) для автокомплита?

Tags: php, mysql, search, autocomplete

**Цель задачи**: реализовать функционал автокомплита адресов (населенные пункты, 3 млн. записей) с 2х символов, 
при этом если не введены символы, должны 10 популярных населенных пункта по кол-ву запросов.

**Сложность в следующем**:
текущая структура БД нашей CMS такая, что адреса (список населенных пунктов со всеми нужными привязанными данными) хранится в 3 таблицах.

Если реализовать автокомплит с поиском по названия используя `SELECT .. LIKE ..` с учетом 2х `JOIN`ов то выборка из БД происходит долго.. если ввести несуществующую сроку, то поиск  работает за 15-30 секунд (индексы созданы). Нужно настолько быстро сделать, чтобы помогало пользователю дополнять текст.

изменять текущую структуру бд нельзя, но возможно на ее основе создать свою.

Какие есть варианты решения задачи?

Возможно, создать отдельную таблицу, с двумя основными полями, `id` - внешний ключ к основной таблице данных, `text` - строка для поиска. Далее искать по этой таблице, чтобы избежать `JOIN`ов,

Или может как-то можно представить в виде двоичного дерева поисков? 
Хранить временную таблицу для поиска в оперативной памяти? и т.д

Comment: Можно попробовать сделать view и обновлять его периодически. Возможно, будет чуть быстрее. Возможно, лучшим решением будет in memory database

Comment: Ваше предложение с отдельной таблицей id, text выглядит очень даже рабочим. Разумеется при наличии индекса на этом текстовом поле и при поиске по первым буквам (а не из середины). Индекс базы данных и есть то самое двоичное дерево поиска. Очень вероятно надо будет добавить еще третье поле - индекс популярности. Его придется при каких то событиях пересчитывать. Но зато его можно использовать при поиске. Хотя возможно этот рейтинг надо держать в некой другой форме что бы БД смогла использовать его прямо в индексе

Comment: Для справки (информация к размышлению) -- в России 2386 городов и поселков городского типа, а общее ко-во населенных пунктов 155511 (перепись 210 года), всего же в мире порядка 3млн. городов (население Земли ~7.5млрд. чел.)

Comment: Можно использовать полнотекстовый индексатор. SphinxSearch или ElasticSearch. Судя по постановке, в такой индекс можно сразу положить все необходимые данные и, для автокомплита не использовать БД. Будет гораздо быстрее плюс плюшки полнотекстового поиска